# How to colorize shell while using rosmake?

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I am a ROS user, and I compile and build packages using the "rosmake" command.
I would be more than happy to know how to see the warnings and the errors coloured in my shell (if possible, using different colours).

Thank you all in advance,
Felix.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11499/how-to-colorize-shell-while-using-rosmake?/) by [Felix Tr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1179/felix-tr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 378 on 2011-10-11

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you aiming specifically at rosmake (i.e. not make in a ROS package)?

The normal make with CMake is colored from CMake and to get colored warnings and errors from g++ I use colorgcc.

1. Install colorgcc by `sudo apt-get install colorgcc`
2. Define a directory where you will have executables in your path, e.g. $HOME/bin (create bin in your home directory)
   3. Add this directory to your path, i.e. `export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH`. Prefereably put that line in your .bashrc or similar, so you only have to do this once
   4. In that directory create symlinks to colorgcc, i.e.:
   <pre>
       ~/bin$ ln -s /usr/bin/colorgcc c++
   ~/bin$ ln -s /usr/bin/colorgcc g++
   ~/bin$ ln -s /usr/bin/colorgcc gcc
   ~/bin$ ln -s /usr/bin/colorgcc cc

   For CMake only the first line is required.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Tr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1179/felix-tr/) on 2011-10-16**:
Hello, the last answer was very helpful, thanks a lot!!! I will try it, and I hope  there will be no problems :)

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-10-13**:
None. Just call make, it will be colorized. I've cleared up the description how to make that happen. As a side effect all calls that you do to c++/g++ (also non-ROS) will be colored - which for me is a desired effect.

**Comment by [Felix Tr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1179/felix-tr/) on 2011-10-12**:
Thank you again, but I still don´t get it.
If I use this line in order to compile my code "make" (inside of the needed package).
What are the changes I should do in the command line in order to receive coloured output of the "make" command?
Thank you again?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-10-12**:
My answer works only for 2. which I usually do. It seems quicker and during development dependencies don't change, but yes rosmake package would be better for that.

**Comment by [Felix Tr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1179/felix-tr/) on 2011-10-12**:
Hello, first of all I want to thank you for your answer. The second thing is that it is not clear for me :). I can compile my code in 2 different ways: 1. Just enter the shell and then use "rosmake my_package_name". 2. Enter into the package Ĩ want to build and using "make". I prefer the first way because in such way (as far as I know) dependencies are solved. I would be grateful to receive an answer "How to colourise errors and warnings in this case"? Thanks in advance.

**Comment by [Susannah](https://answers.ros.org/users/3504/susannah/) on 2013-03-07**:
I've followed your instructions but there is still no color output. Rosmake should color its output by default because compiling errors are not red (and thus hard to find).

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-07**:
This only colors cmake, not rosmake. If you build you packages normally with make everything should be colored. When you use catkin instead of rosmake everything should be colored.